# Spark doesn't conform to expected type TraversableOnce

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val num_idf_pairs = rescaledData.select("item", "features")
    .rdd.map(x => {(x(0), x(1))})

val itemRdd = rescaledData.select("item", "features").where("item = 1")
    .rdd.map(x => {(x(0), x(1))})

val b_num_idf_pairs = sparkSession.sparkContext.broadcast(num_idf_pairs.collect())


val sims = num_idf_pairs.flatMap {
  case (key, value) =>
    val sv1 = value.asInstanceOf[SV]
    import breeze.linalg._
    val valuesVector = new SparseVector[Double](sv1.indices, sv1.values, sv1.size)
    itemRdd.map {
      case (id2, idf2) =>
        val sv2 = idf2.asInstanceOf[SV]
        val xVector = new SparseVector[Double](sv2.indices, sv2.values, sv2.size)
        val sim = valuesVector.dot(xVector) / (norm(valuesVector) * norm(xVector))
        (id2.toString, key.toString, sim)
    }
}
```

The error is doesn't conform to expected type `TraversableOnce`.

When i modify as follows:

```
val b_num_idf_pairs = sparkSession.sparkContext.broadcast(num_idf_pairs.collect())
val docSims = num_idf_pairs.flatMap {
  case (id1, idf1) =>
    val idfs = b_num_idf_pairs.value.filter(_._1 != id1)
    val sv1 = idf1.asInstanceOf[SV]
    import breeze.linalg._
    val bsv1 = new SparseVector[Double](sv1.indices, sv1.values, sv1.size)
    idfs.map {
      case (id2, idf2) =>
        val sv2 = idf2.asInstanceOf[SV]
        val bsv2 = new SparseVector[Double](sv2.indices, sv2.values, sv2.size)
        val cosSim = bsv1.dot(bsv2).asInstanceOf[Double] / (norm(bsv1) * norm(bsv2))
        (id1.toString(), id2.toString(), cosSim)
    }
}
```

it compiles but this will cause an `OutOfMemoryException`. I set `--executor-memory 4G`.

Comment: Imagining that you don't have massive computing resources it doesn't seem too surprising that you run out of memory: if I'm interpreting your code correctly, you are producing a number of `SparseVector`s proportional to the square root of the items in `num_idf_pairs`. You may want to rethink the algorithm you are using to make it take advantage of distributed computing resources. Spark generally behaves poorly otherwise.

Comment: can we see the exact error please

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet:

```
num_idf_pairs.flatMap { 
   ...
   itemRdd.map { ...}
}
```

is not only not valid Spark code (no nested transformations are allowed), but also, as you already know, won't type check, because `RDD` is not `TraversableOnce`.

The second snippet likely fails, because data you are trying to collect and broadcast is to large.

It looks like you are trying to find all items similarity so you'll need Cartesian product, and structure your code roughly like this:

```
num_idf_pairs
  .cartesian(itemRdd)
  .filter { case ((id1, idf1), (id2, idf2)) => id1 != id2 }
  .map    { case ((id1, idf1), (id2, idf2)) => {
    val cosSim = ??? // Compute similarity
    (id1.toString(), id2.toString(), cosSim)
   }}
```